# How to access object array values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object array return from mongoose find method. However it is in below format:

```
var value = [{'value': {'year': 2018, 'month':3, 'count': 123}}];
```

How can I convert it to below:

```
var value = [{'year': 2018, 'month':3, 'count': 123}];
```

I tried below to convert but still print out the original format.

```
var result = [];
result.push(value);

var arr = [];
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(item) {
     arr.push(result[item]);
     console.log(result[item].year); //undefined
     console.log(result[item]['year']; //undefined
})
console.log(arr);
```

Below is the retrieving method.

```
       function findStats(result, cb) {
            monthly_order.find({})
            .select('-_id')
            .sort({
                    "_id.year": 1,
                    "_id.month": 1
                })
            .exec(function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error find: ', err);
                    return cb(err);
                }
                if(!result){
                    return cb({'message':'No Order.'});
                }else{
                    console.log(result);
                    return cb(null, result);
                    //var arr = result.map(x => x.value); 
                    //console.log(arr);
                    //return cb(null, arr);
                }
            }); 
        }
```

[image]

Using .map() solution
[image]

Original output
[image]

Comment: Now that you've included your full block of code, I'm noticing an issue. The `result` that you pass to `findStats` goes completely unused, as it's redefined by `.exec`. Are you sure that `result`, *inside the `.exec(function(err, result) { ... })`*, is what you think it is?

Answer (score 3):

Just `.map` the `.value` properties of every item in the original array to the new array:

```js
var valueArr = [{'value': {'year': 2018, 'month':3, 'count': 123}}];
var newArr = valueArr.map(({ value }) => value);
console.log(newArr);
```

Note that you'll still only have a single object in memory here - mutations to one variable name will result in mutations to the other variable name. If you want to avoid that, *spread* the `value` object in the `.map` callback instead:

```js
var valueArr = [{'value': {'year': 2018, 'month':3, 'count': 123}}];
var newArr = valueArr.map(({ value }) => ({ ...value }));
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to modify each element of an array in the same fashion. This is a use-case for [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var value = [{'value': {'year': 2018, 'month':3, 'count': 123}}];

var result = value.map(x => x.value); //For each item (x), get the "value" property
console.log(result);
```

The code in your question is returning `undefined` because `result[item]` refers to this:

```
{'value': {'year': 2018, 'month':3, 'count': 123}}
```

As you can see, in order to access the `year` property, you'd have to first access the `value` property:

```
result[item]["value"]["year"]
```

Comment: Not sure why the console print out undefined.

Comment: Can you share the code you're trying to use? As you can see in the snippet above, it should not output `undefined`.

Comment: Okay, just included a snapshot of the original output in my question.

Comment: Updated the retrieve method in my question, you can see the console.log(arr) actually return me undefined.

Comment: Then `result` is not what you think it is. On the line before `var arr = result.map(x => x.value); `, do `console.log(result)`, and let us know what it shows. You're taking `result` as an argument in `findStats`, but then *redefining it* as the `result` of `.exec`...that seems strange. You're never using the `result ` that you pass `findStats`.

Comment: The snapshot I provided is what it printed on console.log(result)

Comment: Please add that line to the `findStats` function in your question. I'd like to see where you're logging `result`.

Comment: Please find the edited output, I also remove the result argument, and test again. Still the same

Comment: I included another snapshot, for better understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185102/discussion-between-wynn-teo-and-tyler-roper).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array any push the value of the object to a new array

```js
var value = [{
  'value': {
    'year': 2018,
    'month': 3,
    'count': 123
  }
}];

let newVal = [];
value.forEach(function(item) {
  for (let keys in item) {
    newVal.push(item[keys])

  }
})
console.log(newVal)
```

```html
How can I convert it to below: var value = [{'year': 2018, 'month':3, 'count': 123}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var value = [{'value': {'year': 2018, 'month':3, 'count': 123}}];
var result = [];
value.map(function(val,i){
  for(var j in val){
    result.push(val[j])
  }
})
```